# Wordpress Wp_query object with 2 posts prints only one

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need to display the latest post from 3 categories and two posts from this last one with another HTML formatting. The problem is the last category prints only one post and stops with a `var_dump()` on the object I can see the two posts.

Check the functions here:

```
function destaques( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => 0,
), $atts ) );

$id = array(6,16,10,4);
$posts = array();
$nomesCat = array();

foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 4){
                    //this is the categorie with two posts
        $posts[] = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'category__in' => array($value)));
    } else {
        $posts[] = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($value)));    
    }
    $nomesCat[] = get_category($value);
}
$html = '<ul class="destaques">';

foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->have_posts()){
        while($value->have_posts()){
            $value->the_post();
            if ($nomesCat[$key]->cat_name == 'Colunistas') {
                                    // check for the categorie name, then call another
                                    // function, passing the wp_query object
                $html .= auxiliarColunistas($value);
                break;
            } else {
                //lots of html formatting code
                $html .= '</li>';
            }
        }
    }


}

$html .= '</ul>';
return $html;
```

This is the helper function:

```
function auxiliarColunistas ($posts) {
$html = '<li class="last">';

/*var_dump($posts); this returns two posts!
die;*/

$html .= '<h2>Colunistas</h2>';

if ($posts->have_posts()){

    while ($posts->have_posts()) {
        $posts->the_post();
        //more html formatting code
    }
}
$html .= '</li>';

return $html; }
```

Why does the loop print just one post and stops?

Comment: thank you for the corrections Nick, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it changing this line:

```
if ($value == 4){
                //this is the categorie with two posts
    $posts_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'category__in' => array($value)));
```

to

```
if ($value == 4){
                //this is the categorie with two posts
    $posts_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'category__in' => array($value)));
```

but I still don't understand why the while loop is not getting the last post.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 4){
                    //this is the categorie with two posts
        $posts_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'category__in' => array($value)));
    } else {
        $posts_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($value)));    
    }
    $nomesCat[] = get_category($value);
}
$html = '<ul class="destaques">';

        while($posts_query->have_posts()){
            if ($nomesCat[$key]->cat_name == 'Colunistas') {
                                    // check for the categorie name, then call another
                                    // function, passing the wp_query object
                $html .= auxiliarColunistas($posts_query->the_post());
                break;
            } else {
                //lots of html formatting code
                $html .= '</li>';
            }
```